# SharePoint calendar in weekly buckets

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar

I would like to have a Calendar in SharePoint on premise (2013), that displays in weekly buckets. This is not the SharePoint Calendar week view. I do not want to see all the days in the month but just weeks.

Is there a way to customize SharePoint Calendars to display weekly buckets, or maybe even a 3rd party app that may be used that already does this?